# C# Populate Radiobuttons in a TreeView on PageLoad with a Database Returned Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a TreeView control, and I would like to be able to use radiobuttons instead of checkboxes.  I am currently creating the radiobuttons using the following code:

```
e.Node.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(String.Format("<input type='radio' value='{0}' name='rblMain' /> {1}", value, name), value));
```

Now my question is how can I repopulate the node with the value that I am returned from the database to the correct node and have it be selected?

Thanks, Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this which might be useful:

http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/217059-radiobutton-treeview.aspx

It has the solution to show the radio button before the text and in the node selected event, we have to write the code to deselect the selected nodes and select the current one. Its around 10 to 15 lines code have to write in this event. 
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
TreeNode nodeParent = new TreeNode();
nodeParent.Text = "Parent";

tvwSample.Nodes.Add(nodeParent);
TreeNode nodeChild = new TreeNode();
nodeChild.Text = "Child1";

nodeParent.ChildNodes.Add(nodeChild);
nodeChild = new TreeNode();
nodeChild.Text = "Child1";
nodeParent.ChildNodes.Add(nodeChild);
}
}

protected void tvwChecked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strText = ((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode.Text;
}

In strText you get the text as "Child1", here ads checked ="true" then it comes as checked mode.
And need more information from you. After select the nodes , whats your next step. you sending these to database or based on that r u getting any.

There is also some stuff on here:
http://forums.asp.net/p/1250727/2316073.aspx

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
           e.Node.Text = "<input type='radio' />" + e.Node.Text;
}
```

Additional links on the same subject
http://forums.asp.net/p/1626167/4180796.aspx   and   http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/TreeViewRadioBox.aspx

Comment: After the node is selected the have to click submit then they get saved to the database.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: With the use of radio buttons does that mean that only one node can be selected at a time? Perhaps when you do selected index changed you can set the text of the node to <input type='radio' checked='true'> . you would need to loop though the other nodes to clear the checked values on the other nodes though. you can use the 'tag' property on the node to store data such as the record id so you would know which record needs to be updated in the DB.

Comment: Yes that is correct, that is why I have set the ID property of the input.  That is a great idea.  I will try setting the tag value and see what I can work with.

Comment: Just added a couple of additional links to the main reply which might help